# How to access Facebook newsfeed?

Tags: facebook, api, web-scraping, feed

Facebook deprecated its 'user/home' endpoint which gave access to a users newsfeed. Is there another way to access the newsfeed or at least shared articles by people they are following?
Are developers able to reach out to Facebook and get permission for this kind of thing?

Alternatively, does anyone have advice/experience with scraping a newsfeed?

Comment: no, of course not. they removed access a very long time ago for privacy reasons. apps should not be able to read anything from users who did not authorize it. scraping is not allowed on facebook, btw.

Comment: _“Is there another way to access the newsfeed or at least shared articles by people they are following?”_ - the way to access that, is called the Facebook news feed, and users can visit the Facebook website, or use their mobile apps, to view it  ;-) If 3rd-party apps could easily replicate this, that would be a direct threat to a major part of Facebook’s core business model.